# Get the correct type from a string

Tags: swift

I have a `String` extracted from a `URLComponent` queryItem value. It could be a Bool, Int, Double etc. Is there any way to automatically turn it into its equivalent swift type without having to try casting it like this:

```
let value = queryItem.value
let lowerCase = value.lowercased()
if lowerCase == "true" {
  queryStrings[key] = true
} else if lowerCase == "false" {
  queryStrings[key] = false
} else if let i = Int(value) {
  queryStrings[key] = i
} else if let d = Double(value) {
  queryStrings[key] = d
} else {
  queryStrings[key] = value
}
```

Comment: Don't think so , because they create a string whatever datatype they may be

Comment: For the bool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107051/convert-string-to-bool-in-swift-via-api-or-most-swift-like-approach ?

Comment: No, there is no *smart* way. In Swift 5.7 you can `switch` on a Regex, but this is actually just syntactic sugar.

Comment: When you say "Bool, Int, Double etc.", the "etc." is infinitely long. There is no bound on what types exist. Do you mean some very specific list of types with a specific list of rules for converting them from strings? If so, that's just code you need to write to implement the rules you want to apply. There is no *general* rule that says that "true" is a boolean and not a string. Why is "1.0" a Double, and not a CGFloat (or a string)? These are arbitrary rules you've invented, so you'll need to write down what they are.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way of doing it, here another way of what you were doing

```
let item: Any = (Bool(lowerCase) ?? Int(lowerCase) ?? Double(lowerCase)) ?? value
queryStrings[key] = item
```