# How to take input in swift

Tags: swift, input, boolean, cin, keyboard-input

I was trying to get Boolean data with readLine()! but cannot input it

There was a compilation error saying

---

error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'Bool'

Comment: See [Convert String to Bool in Swift - via API or most Swift-like approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28107051/1187415)

Answer (score 1):

[`readLine()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/readline(strippingnewline:)) returns a `String?`. You cannot implicitly convert a String to Bool.

Swift does not know what strings you consider to be a valid boolean value. Are `0` and `1` considered boolean values by your app? `no` and `yes`? `falsch` and `wahr`? Swift does not know. You need to parse it yourself, for example:

```swift
let myBool: Bool

switch stringInput.lowercased() {
case "false", "no", "0": myBool = false
case "true", "yes", "1": myBool = true
default:
    print("Invalid input")
    return
}

print(myBool)
```